# Mmenu Vertical Submenu w/ JQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Has anyone been able to successfully implement .slideToggle to a vertical submenu as opposed to display:none / display block functionality?

I am able to get it to intermittently work but it's fighting with the built in functionality, which I'm not sure how to disable.

I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation but admittedly this amount of scripting is probably a little over my head.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
$("#dropdown").click(function () {
$(".dropdown-Mmenu").slideToggle("slow", function () {
    // Animation complete.
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ub75faxv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Alright - I actually wasn't too far off, a moment of clarity struck.

Comment out:
`.mm-listview .mm-vertical .mm-panel, .mm-vertical .mm-listview .mm-pane` and
`.mm-vertical li.mm-opened>.mm-panel, li.mm-vertical.mm-opened>.mm-panel` and add `$(".dropdown-Mmenu").hide();` to the above script to set it as hidden on load.

Done.